# How to write a Maven build script to execute Java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

How can I execute a Java program during the build, or after the build has just finished? Is it possible to do this directly from pom?

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.sonatype.mavenbook.weather.Main
```

**EDIT**

Let's say I want to execute `org.eclipse.content.MyClass`. How would I needed to write the code?

This builds the project but it doesn't execute my class:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.eclipse.content.MyClass</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure maven-exec-plugin with your pom

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>yourPhase</phase>
        ...
        <goals>
          <goal>java</goal>
        </goals>
           <configuration>
             <mainClass>mainClass=org.sonatype.mavenbook.weather.Main</mainClass>
          </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

In line `<phase>yourPhase</phase>` insert maven [phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) in what this plugin should run.

This class need to be avaliable in pom classpath (as source or as a dependency). In other case if it shouldn't be a project dependency read [this article](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) how to configure a exec plugin.

Comment: @cetnar what about this ? `<phase>yourPhase</phase>...<goals>` , lets say I wanna execute org.eclipse.content.MyClass how would I needed to write code?

Comment: @Gandalf I've updated my answer. Main class and other parameters you can place in configuration section.

Comment: @cetnar I added mainClass= to the configuration property, stil no result.. maybe I should put the reference to built classes in target instead of org ...

Comment: @cetnar I added `<id>` before phase and it worked .. but now I get Reason: An exception occured while executing the Java class. mainClass=org.sonatype.mavenbook.weather.Main .. it says I get an exeption.. how can I see that exeption, its running ok as a standalone java file..

Comment: @Gandalf. What happened? Any errors? What do you call? Run `mvn deploy` to see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [exec maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)... Oops, I should've read more carefully :-(